# Laravel Jquery Ajax URL include route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, url

I have a route in my web.php:

```
Route::post('/loadtestform', ['as' => 'loadtests', 'uses' => 'FormController@loadtests']);
```

and I have a js-file, which sends an Ajax-request to that route:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: loadtests, 
})
```

It doesn't work, of course. How can I include route `loadtest` in the AJAX URL?

PS. Of course it does work with: "url: '/loadtestform', my question is can I use route name instead of url?:)

Comment: The important thing we need to see is the value of `loadtests`, which you haven't shown....

Comment: I dont' understand your comment, Rory. It's written above: ... ['as' => 'loadtests' ...

Comment: I mean the `loadtests` value in your JS code. That is entirely separate from the laravel route which exists on the server

Comment: hm.... I think it's pretty obvious for someone using Laravel....

Comment: You don't seem to understand my point; Laravel runs on the server. JS runs on the client. The two cannot interact in the manner you're attempting.

Comment: They do interact in this manner: url: '/loadtestform', my question was can I use route-name instead of direct url. If I can't, you can just answer with No and explanation:)

Comment: I'm glad to see you managed to edit the question to more accurately show what you're trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: I get you @RoryMcCrossan I just don't think he gets it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole question is wrong, you're getting confused between PHP and Javascript, you can' just reference PHP variables in Javascript.

What you can do however is the following

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "{{ route('loadtests') }}", 
});
```

This assumes `loadtests` is a valid route and you are using blade to render the template.

Comment: doesn't work:( Yes, "loadtests" is a valid route (I can see it when "php artisan route:list"), and yes, I am using blade to render the template.

Comment: Great, doesn't work, thanks for that in depth explanation.... Seriously, if you want help explain what doesn't work, simply saying 'doesn't work' is not helpful.

Comment: when I use "url: '/loadtestform'" it sends an ajax request and I can see it in development tools. When I use: "url: {{ route('loadtests') }}," I see no corresponding request in devtools. That's what I meant:)

Comment: @SergejFomin What does it show when you `dd(route('loadtests'))`?

Comment: if i insert it in blade, it shows: "http://localhost:8000/loadtestform" which is exactly the same route, as with "url: '/loadtestform".

Comment: I've changed what you suggested to:
url: "{{ route('loadtests') }}"
and now - it works! thanks.:)

Comment: @SergejFomin So the past 40 minutes of debugging has been worthless?

Comment: if you change your answer to the correct one (url: "{{ route('loadtests') }}") I'll accept it as the right answer.

Comment: @SergejFomin hmm, didn't notice the quotes

Comment: parameter send from this format shows variable undefined help